# MongoDB find documents using an array of objects as search argument

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to search a mongodb database using an array of objects as search arguments?

Lets say I have the following search preferences:

```
preferences = [{
    product: "PRODUCT_A",
    minqty: 5,
    maxqty: 50
  },
  {
    product: "PRODUCT_B",
    minqty: 100,
    maxqty: 500
  }
]
```

In my database I have Jobs with the following structure:

```
{
  jobName: "job name",
  items: [{
      product: "PRODUCT_A"
      qty: 25
    },
    {
      product: "PRODUCT_F"
      qty: 300
    }

  ]
}
```

I would like to query the database using preferences and returning any jobs that match **at least one of the criteria's**.

### ATTEMPT 1:

I managed to use all my preferences as filters, but `$match` is cumulative, the way it's written it works like `&&` in javascript. My goal is to have "match THIS `||` match THAT".

```
let pipeline = [];

preferences.map((item) => {
  let search = {
    product: item.product,
    quantity: { $gte: item.minqty, $lte: item.maxqty },
  };

  return pipeline.push({
    $match: {
      items: {
        $elemMatch: search,
      },
    },
  });
});

const jobs = await Job.aggregate(pipeline);
```

### ATTEMPS 2 (SUCCESS):

```
let search = [];

preferences.map((item, index) => {
  let arguments = {
    product: item.product,
    quantity: { $gte: item.minqty, $lte: item.maxqty },
  };

  search.push(arguments);
});

let pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {
      items: {
        $elemMatch: {
          $or: search,
        },
      },
    },
  },
];

const jobs = await Job.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation

1. Denormalize items using `$Unwind`
2. Once denormalized, you can use simple `match` with `$or`
3. Use `$lte` and `$gte`

And update the question with your attempts of these or post a new one.

Comment: thanks for the insight, I'll try and update the question with a resolution guide if possible

Comment: solved the problem, thanks for helping, I had never used aggregation before, it's really powerful tool

Comment: idk if it's appropriate to mark as the solution when $unwind was not necessary

Comment: ElemMatch ll return the first matching element un the array. Not all matching elements